# Tracing root compromises

Tags: linux, centos, security, redhat

In regards to the following:

http://blog.solidshellsecurity.com/2013/02/18/0day-linuxcentos-sshd-spam-exploit-libkeyutils-so-1-9/ http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/18ro3c/sshd_rootkit/

There apparently seems to be a bunch of redhat servers being backdoored via a library. Does anyone have advice on how to track and find the initial breach of contact?

Comment: You may receive better answers to this question on our sister site [security.se]. Be sure to check their FAQ and search for previous questions about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per the links:

"Sounds more like they get in through php, then back-door sshd using a bad library once they have root. The initial attack vector is not a vulnerability in sshd.

After further reading consensus appears to be that the initial attack is done through cpanel on poorly-secured machines. Only 64-bit machines get the back-doored sshd, which is done through /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.9, which shouldn't be present on the system otherwise."

Now why PHP based vulnerability ends up allowing root access is mystery.  May be apache was running with root privileges and thus PHP files also got executed with similar access.  Unless you have PHP / apache running with root privileges, there should be anything to worry about.  As suggested "rpm -qf /lib/libkeyutils.so.1.9" commands can be used to see if you are affected or not.

Comment: I would have to beg to differ. For PHP to be the cause on over 1000 machines means there is some more at fault especially systems running the latest kernels and not too mention CageFS being broken out of. This screams a service exploit